# Symfony and handling Json

Tags: php, json, symfony

First of all, i have to say, I am very new to Symfony.. I need to understand the correct way to do it, as well as where the code goes, and how to output is processed..

I was given a spec to call a web site; 
example;

```
Path:   http://mywebsiteserver.com/getstuff/studentID=100 
Method: GET
```

and it will return a json ;

example;

```
{"response":{"data":[{"StudentID":.....................
```

and i need to parse this data, and display as table on the web site...

What is the right structure for this? If you can direct me in the right direction, all help is greatly appreciated

Comment: this can be done in few lines, but http://whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done by PHP natively.

```
// inside controller
$jsrc = "http://mywebsiteserver.com/getstuff/studentID=100";
$json = file_get_contents($jsrc);
$jset = json_decode($json, true);
```

Then put data wherever you like